# Sorting values of an array type in RDD using pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, sorting, pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD containing values like this:

```
[
   (Key1, ([2,1,4,3,5],5)),
   (Key2, ([6,4,3,5,2],5)),
   (Key3, ([14,12,13,10,15],5)),
]
```

and I need to sort the value of the array part just like this:

```
[
   (Key1, ([1,2,3,4,5],5)),
   (Key2, ([2,3,4,5,6],5)),
   (Key3, ([10,12,13,14,15],5)),
]
```

I find two sorting methods for Spark: `sortBy` and `sortbyKey`. I tried the `sortBy` method like this:

```
myRDD.sortBy(lambda x: x[1][0])
```

But unfortunately, it sort data based on the first element of the array instead of sorting the elements of the array per se.

Also, the `sortByKey` seems not to help cause it just sorts the data based on the keys.

How can I achieve the sorted RDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], sorted(x[1]), x[2]  ))
```

Comment: As I know, `sorted()` is a python function. So is this sorting process distributed? If we can use these such functions, I also can use the NumPy sort function so Which one is better in terms of performance? @thebluephantom

Comment: U r not sorting distributed here. Just an array in an rdd as element.

Comment: So how can I sort elements of the array in a distributed manner? @thebluephantom

Comment: Its a narrow transformation here so it is by default distributed. Believe me pls. U r not sorting the rdd just an element of rdd.